# JSEncrypt Error [Uncaught ReferenceError: ASN1 is not defined] using JavaScript Interpreter

Tags: javascript, runscope, jsencrypt

I wondered if you can help with an issue when using this library in the Runscope JavaScript interpreter(V8-compatible (version 3.28), sandboxed JavaScript interpreter).

I think it's happening because the JSEncrypt code is expecting a browser?

*Error: [Uncaught ReferenceError: ASN1 is not defined]*

Would anyone know how to work around such an issue?

A similar issue has been encountered on [Rhino](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt/issues/21)

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I've updated JSEncrypt as documented here: https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt/issues/21.  Seems to have resolved the asn1 error above.  Although now when I call `var enc = crypt.encrypt(text);` it returns false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must have missed one of the changes when I first attempted updating JSEncrypt as documented here:  https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt/issues/21.

Can confirm encryption is working now.